# Returning Values in Javascript Functions

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, closures, higher-order-functions

I came across this answer while understanding closures by @Jacob Swartwood https://stackoverflow.com/a/6472397/3179569

and I could not understand how `littleGirl` called story as if it was a function. Shouldn't it have been `littleGirl();` so that the `princess` function was called? Also isn't the princess function returning a key value pair, which means it's returning an object? So how can `littleGirl` access a key as if it was a function? (because `story` is a key right?)

I tried searching for the term returning a key value pair in javascript but didn't come up with a decent explanation. I'm hoping someone here can help me. I come with a background in Java and C++ so this is a bit confusing.

```
function princess() {


    var adventures = [];

    function princeCharming() { /* ... */ }

    var unicorn = { /* ... */ },
        dragons = [ /* ... */ ],
        squirrel = "Hello!";


    return {


        story: function() {
            return adventures[adventures.length - 1];
        }
    };
}


var littleGirl = princess();

littleGirl.story();
```

Comment: princess is returning an object (the curly braces) which has a property which is a function (story). So the main code calls princess to get this object (littleGirl) and then calls the story property which is a function. Hope that helps.

Comment: I still didn't get it. Can you access story just like that? Did it get created as a property of princess when it was written after the return statement so that it could be accessed directly later on?

Comment: Look like David did great job explaining, so go with that :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe if we break it down and add one thing at a time it will make more sense.

First, a function `princess` that returns `undefined`:

```
function princess() {
}

princess();

//> undefined
```

Next, a function that returns an object literal:

```
function princess() {
    return {};
}

princess();

//> Object {}
```

Next, a function that returns an object literal with a function inside it (which returns `undefined`):

```
function princess() {
    return {
        story: function {}
    };
}

princess().story();

//> undefined
```

Next, a function that returns an object literal with a function inside that returns an array:

```
function princess() {
    return {
        story: function {
            return [];
        }
    };
}

princess().story();

//> Array []
```

I think that covers *most* of your points.  However, none of this has much to do with closures.  In your example, the array `adventures` is what is being closed over.  This allows kind of a `private` member (like with access modifier in Java).

So, finally, a function that returns an object literal with a function inside which closes over a *private* array:

```
function princess() {
    var myArray = [1, 2, 3];
    return {
        story: function {
            return myArray[myArray.length - 1];  // get the last one: 3
        }
    };
}

princess().story();

//> 3
```

Comment: Thank you. That made a lot more sense now.

Comment: glad to help.  added a bit more that shows a closure.

Comment: I actually couldn't understand how `littleGirl` was able to access `story` directly but I think I get it now.

Comment: Yeah, `littleGirl` is a reference to what `princess()` *returns*.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on what @asantaballa said, `story` is a key with a value of `function () {...}`. If you were to run `console.log(littleGirl.story)` you would see `function princess/<.story()`

Princess could be rewritten like this...

```
function princess() {


    var adventures = [];

    function princeCharming() { /* ... */ }

    var unicorn = { /* ... */ },
        dragons = [ /* ... */ ],
        squirrel = "Hello!";

    var getAdventure = function () {
        return adventures[adventures.length - 1];
    };

    var retObj = new Object(); // same as '{}'
    retObj.story = getAdventure;

    return retObj;
}


var littleGirl = princess();

littleGirl.story();
```

Answer (score 1):

Or in another way, princess is just a function.

You call it with princess() and it returns something.

That something it returns, is an object like this:

```
{
    story:function() {...}
}
```

This object has a function (story) inside.

**A function** is, after all, just some data you can pass around and assign to variables like any other data.

**An object** is a way of grouping different data together into a single.. well.., object

So you can put functions inside objects. And functions can return any data kind, including objects.

```
// set variable aFunc to some function
var aFunc=function() {...}

// call it
aFunc();

// Set an object
var anObj= {
    anInt:3,
    aString:"blabla",
    itsFunction:aFunc
}
```

Call the function inside it

```
anObj.itsFunction();
```

A function returning the same object is

```
function getAnObj() {
    return {
        anInt:3,
        aString:"blabla",
        itsFunction:aFunc
    }
}
```

In our case, princess is just like getAnObj,
story is just like aFunction

So

```
princess().story();
```

is just like

```
var anObj=getAnObj();
anObj.itsFunction();
```

A function (`princess`) returned an object (`littleGirl`) that has a function inside it (`story`). And you call it.

A function (`getAnObj`) returned an object (`anObj`) that has a function inside it (`itsFunction`). And you call it.

Names..